# OS X Keychain Programming Resources

Tags: macos, security, keychain

The only real information I could find on using the OS X keychain API was [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html). Unfortunately, the keychain API is pretty complicated and Apple's docs leave a lot to be desired.

Are there any other good resources on accessing the keychain programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I've concluded that there is no such reference.

I ended up just using the source code to Apple's security tool as usage examples for unclear APIs. [It's open source](http://opensource.apple.com/source/SecurityTool/SecurityTool-55002/), so the code is freely available.

Comment: Any changes to this perchance?